View More for Nested Loops not working ReactJS NextJS
I'm trying to add view more to each of the sec1, sec2 and sec3 section sentences. But on clicking on any of the view more, all the sections get expanded.
I have tried various things googling but cannot get it solved as I'm unable to get what is wrong with the code.
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Result() {

const data = {"data":{"sec1":["my sisters and brothers are near and dear","near neighbors","in the near future","they are near equals","his nearest approach to success","a very near thing","a near hit by the bomb","she was near tears","the near or nigh horse is the one on the left","the animal's left side is its near or nigh side","a near likeness","very close (or near) with his money","near beer","a dress of near satin"],"sec2":["as the wedding day drew near","stood near the door","don't shoot until they come near","getting near to the true explanation","her mother is always near","he nearly fainted","I was near exhausted by the run"],"sec3":["They are drawing near","The enemy army came nearer and nearer"]}};
const [currentSliceStartEx, setCurrentSliceStartEx] = useState(0)
const [currentSliceEndEx, setCurrentSliceEndEx] = useState(2)
const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(null)

const getMoreDataEx = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
    setCurrentSliceStartEx(currentSliceStartEx)
    setCurrentSliceEndEx(currentSliceEndEx == 2 ? -1 : 2);
    setCurrentSection(item);
  }

const InnerContent = (item) => {
    //console.log(item)
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <p key={item.idx} className="">{ item.item }</p>         
        </div>
    );
  };

  const MainContent = (item) => {
    console.log(item)
    return (
        <div key={item.idx} >  
          <p  className={`my-7 sec-${item.item['0']}`}>
            As a {item.item['0']}
          </p>
          { Object.entries(item.item['1']) && Object.entries(item.item['1']).slice(currentSliceStartEx, currentSliceEndEx).map((inneritem) => (
            <InnerContent idx={inneritem['0']} item={inneritem['1']} />
          ))}

          { (currentSliceEndEx < item.item['1'].length) && 
            <span className="cursor-pointer" onClick={()=>getMoreDataEx(item.item)}>View {currentSliceEndEx == 2 ? "more" : "less"}</span>
          }
        </div>
    );
  };

return (
    <>
      {data?.data &&  Object.entries(data?.data).map((item,index) => (
         <MainContent item={item}/>
       ))}
   </>
);
}


Can anyone guide me on how to solve it?

The code you provided is quite confusing. Based on the data you defined, references such as item.idx and item.item is obviously undefined.

@WillCarter Can you try running the code in a next js environment as a new page.jsx file?

It seems issue because of start and end slice indices
maintains separate start and end slice indices for each section (sec1, sec2, sec3).
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Result() {
  const data = {
    data: {
      sec1: [
        "my sisters and brothers are near and dear",
        "near neighbors",
        "in the near future",
        "they are near equals",
        "his nearest approach to success",
        "a very near thing",
        "a near hit by the bomb",
        "she was near tears",
        "the near or nigh horse is the one on the left",
        "the animal's left side is its near or nigh side",
        "a near likeness",
        "very close (or near) with his money",
        "near beer",
        "a dress of near satin",
      ],
      sec2: [
        "as the wedding day drew near",
        "stood near the door",
        "don't shoot until they come near",
        "getting near to the true explanation",
        "her mother is always near",
        "he nearly fainted",
        "I was near exhausted by the run",
      ],
      sec3: [
        "They are drawing near",
        "The enemy army came nearer and nearer",
      ],
    },
  };

  const [sectionsState, setSectionsState] = useState({
    sec1: { start: 0, end: 2 },
    sec2: { start: 0, end: 2 },
    sec3: { start: 0, end: 2 },
  });

  const getMoreDataEx = (sectionKey) => {
    setSectionsState((prevState) => {
      const currentEnd = prevState[sectionKey].end;
      const newEnd = currentEnd === 2 ? -1 : 2;
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [sectionKey]: {
          start: prevState[sectionKey].start,
          end: newEnd,
        },
      };
    });
  };

  const InnerContent = ({ item }) => (
    <div className="container">
      <p>{item}</p>
    </div>
  );

  const MainContent = ({ itemKey, itemValues }) => {
    const { start, end } = sectionsState[itemKey];
    return (
      <div key={itemKey}>
        <p className={`my-7 sec-${itemKey}`}>As a {itemKey}</p>
        {itemValues.slice(start, end).map((innerItem, idx) => (
          <InnerContent key={idx} item={innerItem} />
        ))}
        {end < itemValues.length && (
          <span
            className="cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => getMoreDataEx(itemKey)}
          >
            View {end === 2 ? "more" : "less"}
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data?.data &&
        Object.entries(data.data).map(([key, values]) => (
          <MainContent key={key} itemKey={key} itemValues={values} />
        ))}
    </>
  );
}


Thanks for the solution and the info. Can I get the solution without declaring sec1, sec2, sec3 as they will be dynamic keys from API?
